# Wait for $http promise before the next request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-http, angular-promise

I'm working on an angularJS app and this is my first website using this framework. In my app i've a need to make a $http call inside a for loop. With in the loop before the next iteration I want to wait for the response from my previous call. What is the best and simple way to do this. I've tried using the callBack, $q.all(), .then in all of these only the last request is going through. Please help.

Note: My API that i'm calling through $http can't queue requests.

**Edit:**
 I've tried both the below approaches, in both of the cases only the last request is being made successfully. Can you tell me what is wrong i'm doing here.

Approach 1:

```
var promiseArray=[];

for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
{
 var promise=services.Post(items[i]);
 promiseArray.push(promise);
}

$q.all(promiseArray).then(data)
{
 ...
}
```

Approach 2:

```
var promises = [];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    var deffered = $q.defer();
    var promise = services.Post(items[i]);
    promise.success(function(data) {
        deffered.resolve(data);
    })
    promises.push(deffered);
}
```

var result = $q.all(promises);

**EDIT :2** 
Service Code:

```
Services.Post = function(lineItemId, submitUrl) {
    var url = (submitUrl) ? submitUrl : Services.serviceUrl;

    return $http.post(url, {
        "LineItemID": lineItemId
    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        Services.processResponse(data, status, headers, config);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        JL('Angular').error('Error response when calling Service ' + config);

    });
};
```

Comment: take a look at the async lib (https://github.com/caolan/async) you could load it on the browser via browserify/webpack/jspm

Answer (score 6):

You could use `$q.when` which would take promise of `$http` & when it gets resolved it call the function inside `.then`

```
$q.when(promiseObj).then(callback);
```

If there are multiple promise then you could use `$q.all` which would accept array of promise & called then function when all promise inside the function gets resolved.

```
$q.all([promiseObj1, promiseObj2]).then(callback);
```

**Update**

I think your 1st approach is right only missed couple thing

1. `for` loop condition, which does create an extra object which would be undefined
2. `$q.all` should have function inside `.then`

**Code**

```
var promiseArray=[];

for(var i=0; i < items.length - 1;i++) //<-- change from i<items.length
{
 var promise=services.Post(items[i]);
 promiseArray.push(promise);
}

$q.all(promiseArray).then(function(data) //<-- it should be function in .then
{
  //this will called after all promises get resolved.
});
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj, thanks for the response, I've tried different approaches that i've mentioned above. Please take a look at it and correct me if there is anything wrong.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth your first approach looks cool to..I think in angular service you didn't return a promise, you should have to return promise from service..if you have any doubt then..add you angular service code too..I'll help with that code too

Comment: Thanks for extending your help, i've copied my service code here, could you please take a look at it

Comment: This didn't help me actually, as the service that I'm calling can't queue the requests and can handle requests one after the other.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth you want to maintain synchronize queue?

Comment: yes as my service can't handle the queue, I want my code to stop moving further until the last iteration of my for loop is completed before it executes anything else after the for loop.

Comment: oh..but currently your code is looking for run code after all bunch of promises get complicated..